# How to kill process by specific Id in c#

Tags: c#

I have multiple processes that running at the same time of my C# program and all of this processes have the same name with different ID and I want to kill specific process of my program by their specific ID or rename them and kill it by their specific name.

Answer (score 3):

- [Process.GetProcessById(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid?view=net-6.0)
- [Process.Kill()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-6.0)

---

**Edit**:
Pay attention to **Notes** and **Remarks** sections of the documentation, specially for the `Kill` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id you can do it like this (where `id` is an `int32`):

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(id);
process.Kill();
```

Or if you are using **LinQ** you can do it like this:

```
Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id))
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Kill();
```